# JS is not converting Big Number to a string correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript, numbers, bigint

BTW, I get this number dynamically.

```js
const obj = {
  id:24784909617760986
};


console.log(obj.id.toString()); // "24784909617760984"
```

I want to convert 24784909617760986 to "24784909617760986". How can I do this ?

I have tried to convert this number to a big int and then into a string but its not working correctly

Comment: Your precision is already lost when you create the `BigInt`. Pass the number as string instead.

Comment: I cannot pass the number as a string

Comment: You cannot pass it as number either, as thats the reason the precision is lost.

Comment: How do you get the number dynamically? If you can, edit that code to use bigints.

Comment: An External API give me this number in an object. When I try to store this number as a string, its original value is lost

Comment: *I want to convert 24784909617760986 to "24784909617760986"*: you cannot because `24784909617760986===24784909617760984` is a true expression

Comment: Does that API answer with JSON? In that case, you have a string representation, and you should use a "reviver" function when parsing that JSON, so that you can decode that JSON into BigInt numbers where necessary.

Comment: I was writing an answer and the question got closed before i could, the explanation behind the failure is that the number ur using is greater than the maximum allowed number that can be safely used (Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), since its greater it'll use double precision and cause irregularities. only way to solve is to take the number as a string itself and then split it and use smaller numbers

Comment: `I get this number dynamically` - it's important to know exactly how